# Joining table with address data to a shapefile (buildings) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

The aim is to show all mineral oil deposits of an specific area.

First I have the buildings as a shapefile. The address of every building is divided in City, street and housenumber. So there are three different attributes.

And I got a table with all addresses that have a mineral oil deposit. ( I know how to import it into QGIS as a csv-file). In this table the address is also divided in three attributes as in the shapefile of the buildings.

The problem is I have no single attribute that could be used for a join. Do you know any easy possibility to join them? Maybe to put the attribute street and the house number in one attribute?

Comment: just to be sure: both tables seem to have similar attribute fields...do they differ in format or do the field values not match?...why can't you use them exactly? and do both have geometries (for then @ahmadhanb's answer is a solid solution)

Comment: yes the adresses would match but I can't join them by the single attribut street or house number, since there are a lot of streets with more than one mineral oil deposit. 

the table has no geometries. its just an excel-file (Excuse me, thank you)

Comment: I see...well, if you are sure that using two fields (e.g. street + housenr) would give you unique matches in both tables, you could alwas create a new column in both layers and populate them with streetname + housenr as one value (e.g. combine them - you can use the qgis field calculator for this) to perform the join. http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html

Answer (score 3):

If the attribute table cannot be used to join the data together, you can use join by location from `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join attributes by location`.

[image]

You need to select the `target layer` whether it is building layer or oil field layer and select in the `Join vector layer` the other layer.

If the data do not have any coordinates and just the address, you can use [mmqgis plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/) and use Geocode to get the location based on address. You can refer to [How to Geocode Addresses Using QGIS](https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-geocode-addresses-using-qgis/) for more information.

Comment: a table havn't got any spatial references, isnt it? So I can't join them by location, right? Or is there a possibility to generate a spatial reference to the table by the address attributes?
Excuse me I'm still on beginner level